# Active a customer doesn't work in Magento

Tags: magento

Let me make clear the context:

Look at the `customer_entity` table:

```
+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------+----------------------+----------+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| entity_id | entity_type_id | attribute_set_id | website_id | email                | group_id | increment_id | store_id | created_at          | updated_at          | is_active |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------+----------------------+----------+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|         1 |              1 |                0 |          1 | john.doe@example.com |        1 | 000000001    |        1 | 2007-08-30 23:23:13 | 2008-08-08 12:28:24 |         1 |
|         2 |              1 |                0 |          1 | vietean@gmail.com    |        1 |              |        1 | 2011-08-15 09:51:20 | 2011-09-06 07:31:17 |         0 |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------+----------------------+----------+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

At the customer has id is 2 and `is_active` attribute is 0, now I want to change to 1.

```
$customerId = 2;
$modelCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$modelCustomer->setIsActive(1);
$modelCustomer->save();
```

But, it doesn't work.
How can I fix it or I am missing something?

Update:

I can getIsActive of this customer.

```
$modelCustomer->getIsActive();//0
```

Debugging:

When I showed log, I just saw, I guessed it did not update `is_active` attribute:

```
UPDATE `customer_entity` SET `entity_id` = ?, `entity_type_id` = ?, `attribute_set_id` = ?, `website_id` = ?, `email` = ?, `group_id` = ?, `increment_id` = ?, `store_id` = ?, `created_at` = ?, `updated_at` = ? WHERE (entity_id='2')
```

Comment: is your request executed from top to bottom and you are not calling any exit(); die(); or similar between your tests? Chance is that your transaction is not executed.

Comment: @Aton: I don't think so, because I don't use `exit` or `die` function. And others attribute which belong to `customer_eav_attribute` can update normally. Could you give me another solution? Thanks you so much.

Comment: next step would be logging all queries and see how the query is built

Comment: @Aton: I used `xdebug`, and it worked properly with a transition. But I saw in MySQL's log. It did not update `is_value` column at `customer_entity` table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fur customer entity you need to create static attribute with the same name as field you created. For example, your sql installer can be something like this:

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('customer_entity'), 'is_active', "TINYINT(2)");

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'is_active', array(
'label'         => 'Active',
'type'          => 'static',
'visible'       => 1,
'required'      => 0,
'position'      => 1,
));
```

If you need explanation of this you can debug saving process.

Comment: Sorry @azakolyukin, I don't understand so much. You know, the `customer_entity` has the `is_active` column. And why we need to do above?

Comment: @vietean what he means is if you make a custom field to DB you also have to make a custom attribute for your model so it will know what to bass to db

Comment: @Anto S: Really, he means if in `customer_entity` have an attribute such as: email... we must create same a `custom attribute` like `email` in table `customer_eav_attribute` & `eav_attribute`? So, how about if we get or update value for `email attribute`?

Comment: @vietean maybe this already exists for built in fields? EAV is just clumsy way to manage extendable schemas

Comment: @Anton S: How about in my case?

Comment: Yes, there is standard magento field "is_active" in "customer_entity" table. But in order to change its value you need to have static attribute. unfortunately such attribute doesn't exist by default. This is bug of magento. To make it work just add static attribute like "email". It will work. I've checked it

Comment: It's even enough to add attribute manually to test it. But I recommend you to add installer.

Comment: @azakolyukin: Now I got what you said. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In order to show and use **is_active** field of the table **customer_entity**
```

step 1) paste this code in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Setup.php

```
 'is_active' => array(
                        'label'         => 'MyActive',
                        'type'          => 'static',
                        'input'         => 'text',
                        'visible'       => true,
                        'required'      => false,
                        'position'      => 65,
                    ),

step 2) run this query in phpmyadmin
select * from core_resource;
find the version of customer_setup
for example if in your store this is 1.6.2.0.5 so make a file by this name:
upgrade-1.6.2.0.5-1.6.2.0.6.php
this means from version 1.6.2.0.5 will be upgrade to 1.6.2.0.6
copy this file in this path:
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/

copy this code in it:
$installer = $this;

$middlenameAttributeCode = 'is_active';

$installer->addAttribute('customer', $middlenameAttributeCode, array(
    'type'       => 'static',
    'label'      => 'MyActive',
    'input'      => 'text',
    'required'   => 0,
    'sort_order' => 50,
    'is_visible' => 1,
    'visible'       => 1,
    'position'   => 65,
));

$middlenameAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', $middlenameAttributeCode);
$middlenameAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
    'checkout_register',
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'adminhtml_checkout'
));
$middlenameAttribute->save();
```

step3) goto this path: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml , in above of the code in tag `<version>1.6.2.0.4</version>`, replace your new version

flush all caches

admin logout then login

goto manage customers

Comment: Please don't forget to add your new code version to config.xml in this path:  app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml in this tag: